# Fetch list items

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have to get list items and need to bind it to a html image button...
I wrote code to fetch list items so may I know how to pass that value to image button

```
using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite("<Site URL>"))     
{      
   using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())     
   {     
      SPList spList = objWeb.GetList("<List URL>");     
      SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();     
      spQuery.Query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query> "; 

      spQuery.RowLimit = 5; 

     SPListItemCollection spListItemCollection = spList.GetItems(spQuery);
  } 
}
```

Now I need to pass this ID column to html image button dynamically.

Comment: What ID column you need to pass and where? Please revise your question.

Comment: I need to pass that items to Image buttons, if I click on image button it will navigate to that item details @jussi palo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access HTML controls from code behind then you should add property runat="server"

Now you can access it using the ID of the control as

```
ImgTagID.Src = spListItemCollection[0]["Id"].ToString();
```